# access table name in subquery trough main query

Tags: mysql

There is a table `questions` has a column `service_table` containing another table name in the database.
i need to access this table name in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` AS `q` 
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT * 
 FROM
  `q`.`service_table` AS `ent1` 
 WHERE ent1.user_id = q.user_id)
```

running this query result in an error :

> *table q.service_table does not exist*

question table schema :

```
id       user_id  service_type    service_id    title   description  
------  -------  --------------  ------------  ------  -----------  
 1       83       translates         1           nana   hi there
```

`translates` table (one of question related services) schema :

```
  id      user_id  context
 ------  -------  --------------   
 1       83          something
```

Comment: provide your tables schema

Comment: Sounds like a bad table schema. Why you did something like this? Mysql is a relational database and this has not the dynamic behaviour you want! You know what relational means? One question has many translations e.g.  You should overthink your schema.

Comment: Im not sure what you are talking about , but i multiple tables `translates`, `typings`, `theses` that can be related to a specific question ,so whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i need to access this table name in a subquery

Not possible.

There is a well-defined boundary in all dialects of SQL for things that the server must understand when the query is initially parsed.  They can't be provided "later" (from the row data, for example).  Object identifiers are one of those things -- schema/table/column names are established before any rows are examined.

There is an alternative, here, and if it seems sketchy, then this is because your design is unconventional.

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM questions q
 WHERE CASE q.service_table
       WHEN 'translates'
       THEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM translates x WHERE x.user_id = q.user_id)
       WHEN 'typings'
       THEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM typings x WHERE x.user_id = q.user_id)
       WHEN 'theses'
       THEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM theses x WHERE x.user_id = q.user_id)
       ELSE NULL END;
```

A more correct design would be a table, such as "service" where each service has an id and a name and a table such as "user_has_service" which has user_id and service_id, both of which are the primary key.

Then in the "question" table, use the service_id.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM question q
  JOIN user_has_service h
    ON h.user_id = q.user_id
   AND h.service_id = q.service_id;
```

Simpler, no?  This will perform better, be easier to maintain, is consistent ith principles of relational database design, and you need no separate table for each individual service.

Comment: thanks. i probably confused you with simplified example of my problem , in fact i have multiple service tables that i need also access their columns values in the main query . so i have two choices : first i can `left join` with all services and verify the conditions to find the related service table or do as you describe with `case`  statement. but i'm not sure pivot table solution works  as you suggested because i need access service table data (a polymorphic relation ). i was thought subquer speed  speed up the run time , but seems its not true, so i came back to `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.* FROM questions q
INNER JOIN translates ent1
 ON ent1.user_id = q.user_id
```

**Note** I thing you can not use dynamic table name in query. It is not allowed.

Comment: Error Code: 1146
Table 'pnu.service_table' doesn't exist